# Dual Boot Woes: Resolving Boot Loader Conflicts between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've recently set up a dual-boot system with Ubuntu and Windows on my machine, but I'm encountering issues with the boot loader. Specifically, I'm facing conflicts between the Ubuntu GRUB and the Windows Boot Manager.

Here's a brief overview of the problem: When I start my computer, sometimes it boots directly into Ubuntu without showing the GRUB menu or options to choose Windows. On other occasions, it boots straight into Windows, and I don't see an option to access Ubuntu through GRUB.

Can someone guide me through the steps to resolve these conflicts and ensure a smooth dual-boot experience? Any insights, tips, or specific commands to troubleshoot and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have Windows 11 (home edition) and Ubuntu 22.04

Thank you in advance.

I've tried a few solutions such as updating GRUB, repairing the Windows Boot Manager, and adjusting UEFI/BIOS settings, but the problem persists

Comment: Are you sure the Windows/Power option (advanced/show hidden yada yada) of Fast Start is off?  That basically hibernates and skips boot altogether.  Some times a Windows update will turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE line to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

then run `update grub`

Hopefully you will then always get the grub menu before Ubuntu boots.

Also, depending on what bios you have, you should be able to hit a key during POST (<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> usually) to enter the EFI boot selection menu, which would let you directly pick either the windows boot loader or the linux boot loader.  This might be a good temporary solution, while you work on adjusting the bootloaders.

Similarly, from the bios, you should be able to select boot options to pick which one is default, and some bioses let you immediately boot one of those options directly from the bios screen.